# Draw text with overlay in center of rectangle (ProgressBar)

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I'm extending build-in progress bar with ability to display progress as percentage, as below:

[image]

I'm trying to add overlay to displayed text, so it will be more readable. I've managed to add it, but now my text is misaligned:

[image]

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg == 0x000F)
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
        {
            var newText = Math.Floor(((float) Value/Maximum)*100).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + '%';
            SizeF textSize = graphics.MeasureString(newText, Font);

            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

            if (Overlay)
            {
                var p = new GraphicsPath();
                p.AddString(
                    newText,
                    Font.FontFamily,
                    (int) Font.Style,
                    Font.SizeInPoints,
                    new Point((int) ((Width - textSize.Width)/2), (int) ((Height - textSize.Height)/2)),
                    StringFormat.GenericDefault);

                graphics.FillPath(brush, p);
                graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), p);
            }
            else
            {
                graphics.DrawString(newText, Font, brush, (Width - textSize.Width) / 2, (Height - textSize.Height) / 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix text size and alignment when using `g.DrawPath` instead of `g.DrawString`.
Ideally I would like to get text from first screen, but with overlay.

Below is full code of my control:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Misiu.Controls
{
    public sealed class ProgressBarWithText : ProgressBar
    {

        public ProgressBarWithText()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            ForeColor = Color.White;
            BackColor = Color.Black;
        }

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams result = base.CreateParams;
                if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT
                    && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
                {
                    result.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // WS_EX_COMPOSITED 
                }

                return result;
            }
        }

        public bool Overlay { get; set; }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == 0x000F)
            {
                using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
                using (var brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
                {
                    var newText = string.Empty;

                    switch (DisplayStyle)
                    {
                        case ProgressBarDisplayStyle.ValueAndMax:
                            newText = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Value, Maximum);
                            break;
                        case ProgressBarDisplayStyle.Text:
                            newText = Text;
                            break;
                        case ProgressBarDisplayStyle.Percentage:
                            newText = Math.Floor(((float) Value/Maximum)*100).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + '%';
                            break;
                    }
                    //var newText1 = DisplayStyle == ProgressBarDisplayStyle.Percentage ? Value == 0 ? "0%" : Math.Floor(((float)Value / Maximum) * 100).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + '%' : DisplayStyle == ProgressBarDisplayStyle.ValueAndMax ? string.Format("{0}/{1}", Value,Maximum) : Text;
                    SizeF textSize = graphics.MeasureString(newText, Font);

                    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
                    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
                    graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                    //graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                    if (Overlay)
                    {
                        var p = new GraphicsPath();
                        p.AddString(
                            newText,
                            Font.FontFamily,
                            (int) Font.Style,
                            Font.SizeInPoints,
                            new Point((int) ((Width - textSize.Width)/2), (int) ((Height - textSize.Height)/2)),
                            StringFormat.GenericDefault);

                        graphics.FillPath(brush, p);
                        graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), p);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        graphics.DrawString(newText, Font, brush, (Width - textSize.Width)/2, (Height - textSize.Height)/2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private ProgressBarDisplayStyle _displayStyle = ProgressBarDisplayStyle.Percentage;

        //Property to set to decide whether to print a % or Text
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Browsable(true)]
        public ProgressBarDisplayStyle DisplayStyle
        {
            get { return _displayStyle; }
            set
            {
                if (_displayStyle == value) return;
                _displayStyle = value;
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Browsable(true)]
        public override string Text
        {
            get { return base.Text; }
            set
            {
                base.Text = value;
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Browsable(true)]
        public override Font Font
        {
            get { return base.Font; }
            set
            {
                base.Font = value;
                Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

    public enum ProgressBarDisplayStyle
    {
        Percentage,
        ValueAndMax,
        Text
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Most of the problem is fixed thanks to @Hans Passant, but text is still misaligned a bit, as shown below:

[image]

Left progressbar is using `Lucida Handwriting, 30pt, style=Bold` and right `Microsoft Sans Serif, 20pt.
Text is moved a bit to bottom right.

Below is comparison of my control with and without overlay:

[image]

Comment: When you provide the location, rather than using the height and width of the form, add a panel to the form and change the DockStyle to "Fill" and then use the Height and width of this panel.

Comment: @Rariolu I'm extending ProgressBar control, so no form in in. I'll add full code to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to align the entire text within the control's client rectangle via StringFormat:

```
StringFormat format = new StringFormat()
{
    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
};
float emSize = graphics.DpiY * Font.Size / 72;
var p = new GraphicsPath();
p.AddString(
    newText,
    Font.FontFamily,
    (int)Font.Style,
    emSize ,
    ClientRectangle, // !!!
    format); // !!!
```

This approach allows to get rid any measuring and location calculation and it always makes the things correctly aligned to me.

Comment: Thank You for that! Only thing I've added is `Trimming = StringTrimming.None, FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap` to format. I've tried doing similar thing with p.Transform, but Your solution is better and easier.

Comment: And I've changed `Font.Size` to `Font.Height`

Comment: It is incorrect to use the `Font.Height`, because it should be [em-Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142535(v=vs.110).aspx)(the height of the em square box that bounds the character). Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I didn't knew about em-Size (that it should be used in `AddString`), already fixed in my code. Thanks for help!